# If statement not working in vb6

Tags: winapi, vb6

I want to make a program which could close a window with the title "Personalization" in vb6. The problem is that the if statement is not working.Here's my code(it only finds a window named "Personalization" without closing it):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Timer1.Enabled = Not Timer1.Enabled
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Dim hwnd As Long, lenght As Long
    Dim title As String

    hwnd = GetForegroundWindow

    lenght = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
    title = Space$(lenght + 1)
    GetWindowText hwnd, title, lenght + 1

    title = Mid(title, 1, lenght + 1)

    t.Text = title
    t.SelStart = Len(t.Text)
    If title = "Personalization" Then End

End Sub
```

The last condition is not working although I clicked on the "Personlization" window and I could see its title in the textbox.

Here's how it's working the if statement:

```
if t.text="Personalization" then end
```

So why it's not working the if statement in the first example? Sorry for my mistakes(this is not my original language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Mid()` statement is wrong.  The third parameter needs to be `length - 1` instead of `length + 1` to strip off the null terminator:

```
title = Mid(title, 1, length - 1)
```

Since you are not stripping the null terminator, your `title` variable does not actually contain `"Personalization"` by itself, thus your comparison fails.  Your text box appears correct because assigning the `Text` property ultimately causes the text box to receive a `WM_SETTEXT` message, which takes a null terminated string as input, so any extra nulls are ignored.

A better option is to use the return value of `GetWindowText()` instead, which is the *true* length copied into the `title` minus the null terminator:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Dim hwnd As Long, lenght As Long
    Dim title As String

    hwnd = GetForegroundWindow

    lenght = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd) + 1
    title = Space$(lenght)
    lenght = GetWindowText(hwnd, title, lenght)

    title = Mid(title, 1, lenght)

    t.Text = title
    t.SelStart = Len(t.Text)
    If title = "Personalization" Then
      ' ...
    End If

End Sub
```